# Using extension to create outlets act weird in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iboutlet, swift-extensions

here is my cell class when I'm using extension to create the outlet. and setting the value using didSet method by checking the row index. when I'm scrolling the values change in weird way.

```
import UIKit

class MyLabelCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    override func setcellUI() {
        setbuttonUI()
    }

    var rowIndex: Int! {
        didSet {
            switch rowIndex {
            case 2:
                myLabel.text = "2222"
            case 9:
                myLabel.text = "9999"
            default:
                myLabel.text = "0000"
            }
        }
    }
}

private var myLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
extension MyLabelCell {
    fileprivate func setbuttonUI() {

        let fontScaller = deviceWidth/375

        myLabel = UILabel()
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myLabel.textAlignment = .center
        myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 15 * fontScaller)
        myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
        myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        myLabel.text = "BUTTON"
        addSubview(myLabel)

        let buttonLeft = deviceWidth/25
        let buttonRight = -deviceWidth/25
        let buttonHeight = deviceHeight/14.82

        let buttonlabelConstraints = [myLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: buttonLeft),
                                      myLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: buttonRight),
                                      myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                                      myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight)]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(buttonlabelConstraints)
        myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
        myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

> Then If I create Outlets without using extensions then it works properly. it doesn't repeat values and does not act weird. below is my code.

```
import UIKit

class MyLabelCell: BaseTableViewCell {

    let buttonLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    override func setcellUI() {
        addSubview(buttonLabel)
        let buttonLeft = deviceWidth/25
        let buttonRight = -deviceWidth/25
        let buttonHeight = deviceHeight/14.82

        let buttonlabelConstraints = [buttonLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: buttonLeft),
                                      buttonLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: buttonRight),
                                      buttonLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                                      buttonLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight)]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(buttonlabelConstraints)
    }

    var rowIndex: Int! {
        didSet {
            switch rowIndex {
            case 2:
                buttonLabel.text = "22222"
            case 3:
                buttonLabel.text = "33333"
            case 4:
                buttonLabel.text = "44444"
            case 7:
                buttonLabel.text = "77777"
            case 9:
                buttonLabel.text = "99999"
            default:
                buttonLabel.text = "00000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**isn't it good to use extension to create outlets ??? ** and why it act so weird. if someone could explain this, then this would be great. hope your help with this to get it understand. Thank you all, cheers!! and happy belated christmas.

Comment: Can you clarify "weird"?  Also, you don't have any `@IBOutlets`, you are using programmatic views.  It is a poor design to have the cell itself have any knowledge of its row; that logic belongs in the view controller.  Most importantly, however, the two pieces of code are not equivalent. In the first instance you are creating additional `UILabels` each time the cell is re-used, while in the second instance you are continually adding the same text field and adding duplicate constraints.  Neither is correct, but you don't have extra labels in the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

it is because in second code each time cell is created new label is created here for each cell

```
 let buttonLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()
```

while in your extension code you are creating only it once and assigning it to cell and UILable is reference type you are getting weird behaviour

in this Line:`private var myLabel: UILabel = UILabel()`